# WMI Win32_VideoController RAM 4GB Limit

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I use WMI Win32_VideoController, AdapterRAM property to read the display adapter RAM size in Windows 10, but the problem is that the value is limited to 4GB maximum.

On a display adapter with 11GB I still get 4GB (and yes I use int64 for the result, but the returned object contains 4GB even if inspected with the debugger).

Is there a way to get around this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've seen the same incorrect "solution" posted in several places. The script @samuel-kriikkula posted only works if you have a single graphics adapter. With more than one adapter, it loops through them incorrectly showing something like:

```
Model                                   VRAM
-----                                   ----
NVIDIA RTX A5500                 21464350720
NVIDIA RTX A4500                 21464350720
Microsoft Remote Display Adapter 21464350720
NVIDIA RTX A5500                 25757220864
NVIDIA RTX A4500                 25757220864
Microsoft Remote Display Adapter 25757220864
```

There's no need to poll `CIM_VideoController`, when the registry entry we already queried contains the adapter name. The following script works properly to gather graphics memory details for every installed adapter.

```
$adapterMemory = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0*" -Name "HardwareInformation.AdapterString", "HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize" -Exclude PSPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

foreach ($adapter in $adapterMemory) {
  [PSCustomObject] @{
    Model=$adapter."HardwareInformation.AdapterString"
    "VRAM (GB)"=[math]::round($adapter."HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"/1GB)
  }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
Model            VRAM (GB)
-----            ---------
NVIDIA RTX A4500        20
NVIDIA RTX A5500        24
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check this **POWERSHELL** code out:

```
$qwMemorySize = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0*" -Name HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)."HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"
foreach ($VRAM in $qwMemorySize)
{
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_VideoController | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.AdapterDACType -ne "Internal"} | ForEach-Object -Process {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Model      = $_.Caption
            "VRAM, GB" = [math]::round($VRAM/1GB)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Model                         VRAM, GB
-----                         --------
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER        8
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But the Class ID is always the same on all computers?

Comment: Yes according to this it appears stable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/system-defined-device-setup-classes-available-to-vendors